# First Database: How does my table structure look?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I am creating my first database to help me organize my leads for a direct mail campaign i'm about to start. i don't know a lot about creating databases but please take a look at my current set up and provide feedback

I Have three parent tables:

```
LeadHeader
MailHeader
Campaign
```

I have three child tables:

```
LeadDetails
MailDetails
CampaignDetails
```

Here are my Tables:

**LeadHeader**

```
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
LeadType (Bankruptcy, NOO OOS, Empty Nesters, inheritance)
LeadSource (Driving For Dollars, Cold Calling, ListSource)
FirstName
LastName
Street
HouseNumber
City
State
Phone
MailingInd (Y/N)
CampaignName (Name of campaign from the MailHeader table)
ResponseInd (Y/N)
AppointmentInd (Y/N)
AcceptedOfferInd (Y/N)
```

**LeadDetail**

```
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
ParentLeadGuid (Links to the Parent Table LEADERHEADER)
Year Built
Purchase Date
Bedrooms
Bathrooms
AssessedValue
Response
Response Date
Notes
```

**MailHeader**

```
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
CampaignName (Name of campaign from the MailHeader table)
CampaignStartDate
CampaignEndDate 
NumberOfMailings (Total number of mailings)
ResponseIND
```

**MailDetail**

```
ParentGuid (Links to the Parent Table MailHeader)
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
MailingNumber (1st,2nd,3rd,4th,ect)
MailingDate (**/**/****)
MailType (Postcard, Letter)
MailMessage
ResponseID (Unqiue identifier for responses since there can be multiple)
Response (Message of response)
```

**Campaign**

```
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
CampaignName
CampaignStartDate
CampaignEndDate
NumberofLeadsMailed
NumberofCallsReceived
AcceptedOfferInd (Y/N)
AcceptedOfferNumber (7)
AppointmentInd (Y/N)
ApointmentNumber (20)
```

**Campaigndetails**

```
Guid (Unqiue identifier)
ParentGuid (Links to the Parent Table Campaign)
PositiveCalls (Leads to in person meeting)
NetrualCalls (Inquiring Information but not meeting. Not angry)
NegativeCalls (People who don't want to be contacted)
AppointmentID
ApointmentNotes
AcceptedOfferID
AcceptedOfferNotes
```

Thanks for any feedback!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is essentially to not repeatedly enter information, so that when you change something (like a Campaign Name), you don't have to change it everywhere that name is used.

That said, without knowing what your actual data looks like, my advice will be somewhat limited, and may be inapplicable. However, there are a couple of changes I would make to accomplish the above.

First, I would create the following "child" tables:

**LeadType**

```
LeadTypeID int PK
LeadTypeDescription varchar(50)
_With data:_
1 'Bankruptcy'
2 'NOO OOS'
3 'Empty Nesters'
4 'Inheritance'
```

**LeadSource**

```
LeadSourceID int PK
LeadSourceDescription varchar(50)
_With data:_
1 'Driving For Dollars'
2 'Cold Calling'
3 'ListSource'
```

**Campaign**

```
CampaignID GUID PK
CampaignName varchar(50)
CampaignStartDate date
CampaignEndDate date
NumberofLeadsMailed smallint
NumberofCallsReceived smallint
AcceptedOfferInd bit
AcceptedOfferNumber smallint
AppointmentInd bit  ?? 
ApointmentNumber smallint  ??
```

And then use references to those tables in place of the references in the original tables. ie `LeadHeader.CampaignName` This looks like what you intended with your `Campaign` table, it just needs to include all the information related to that campaign (with appropriate links as needed), and then just reference the `GUID` from that table.

Second, make sure that you won't have to duplicate any other information when you enter a record. For instance, if you can have multiple appointments for a campaign, you may want a separate `Appointments` table, with relevant data.

Third, I don't know what database you are using, but make sure the datatypes of your columns are appropriate. A Yes/No is a `boolean` or a `bit`. A field to hold an address doesn't need to be 10 characters. A `char` datatype is fixed-width, whereas a `varchar` datatype is variable-length. Consider how much data you'll have and how much space you can allocate to that database. Depending on what type of data you have, you may have to use `nvarchar` or the like.

Fourth, don't make too many assumptions about your data. A person's name doesn't always have to consist of characters. 'John Smith' is just as valid as 'John O'Smith' and is just as valid as 'Johnny5 O'Smith'. Also, your `houseNumber` won't necessarily always be a number. 'Apt. 3B' is a valid house number.

Fifth, give enough space in your columns, but not too much. One of those assumption you can probably safely make is that you probably don't need a `FirstName` field that is `varchar(max)` or probably not even `varchar(1000)`. You'll have to judge what's appropriate based on your expected use.

Sixth, you don't necessarily have to put it in place in advance, but be aware of the changes you may have to make with extreme expansion or relocation. Will your database scale if you acquire a million new users? What if your system moves to Japan?

Seventh, time. Decide where you want your dates to originate from. My suggestion would be using UTC, and then you can always easily calculate your display from your location. But again, this will depend on your data and expectations. Just make sure that if you move to a different time zone, you don't blow yourself up. And don't forget about the quirks of Savings Time or Leap Time. Time can be a major headache.

There are a bazillion other considerations when building a database. And your structure may change as you're building it out, or even after you start using it.

**TL;DR:** *"Weeks of programming can save you hours of planning."* > [https://www.amazon.com/Weeks-programming-hours-planning-T-Shirt/dp/B071NYC13G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071NYC13G)